# Extracting numbers from a string using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I am clueless about regular expressions, but I know that they're the right tool for what I'm trying to do here: I'm trying to extract a numerical value from a string like this one:

```
approval=not requested^assignment_group=12345678901234567890123456789012^category=Test^contact_type=phone^
```

Ideally, I'd extract the following from it: `12345678901234567890123456789012` None of the regexes I've tried have worked. How can I get the value I want from this string?

Comment: What is the regex you've tried?

Comment: Is it the only number you'll ever have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mystr.match(/assignment_group=([^\^]+)/)[1]; //=> "12345678901234567890123456789012"
```

This will find everything from the end of "assignment_group=" up to the next caret `^` symbol.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using it now. But if there is no number, how do I handle the error? I have: Evaluator.evaluateString() problem

Comment: Do `var match = mystr.match(/assignment_group=([^\^]+)/), result = match ? match[1] : '';` to avoid the error and get an empty string instead.

Answer (score 7):

This will get all the numbers:

```
var myValue = /\d+/.exec(myString)
```

Comment: If you want an array of more than one match use `myString.match(/\d+/g)`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
/\^assignment_group=(\d*)\^/
```

This will get the number for `assignment_group`.

```
var str = 'approval=not requested^assignment_group=12345678901234567890123456789012^category=Test^contact_type=phone^',
    regex = /\^assignment_group=(\d*)\^/,
    matches = str.match(regex),
    id = matches !== null ? matches[1] : '';
console.log(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no chance of there being numbers anywhere but when you need them, you could just do:

```
\d+
```

the \d matches digits, and the + says "match any number of whatever this follows"

Comment: The regex I've trid was a simple \bassignment_group. I've managed to find another way, by checking the position, and using substring ... it works. But I thought it could have been a nice way to learn regex !

Comment: well if you're trying to learn regex, I'd suggest the tutorial on w3schools.org, though I normally don't recommend that site.